# how to change assignment of colors to labels from palette in python Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

how can you change the order of colors used by seaborn? example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3], "y": [1,1,1], "color": ["a", "b", "c"]})
sns.pointplot(x="x", y="y", hue="color", data=data)
```

how can the assignment of colors from the default palette, in "hue" be changed? for example, rather than having (blue, green, red) from the palette, having (green, blue, red)? I want to keep the same palette, just change the order of colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pointplot` accepts a dictionary with the level names in the keys and color names in the values, so you could do that. In other words, `palette=dict(a="g", b="b", c="r")`. That is safest, but if you know the order of hues you're going to get (or specify it), you can also do `palette=["g", "b", "r"]`.

Comment: but here I want to use the three colors from the default palette, which aren't "g", "b", "r" - they're different colors. how can I get these? is there a function that given a number of categories will return the hex codes for those from the default palette?

Comment: Oops, forgot, if you do `sns.set_color_codes()` or `sns.set(color_codes=True)` it will make matlab interpret the single letter strings as seaborn colors.

Answer (score 4):

The [Seaborn docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html) on palettes dance around this, but here's how it works:

- First, note that `color_palette()` will return your current color palette.
- Second, do the example from the docs and assign the current palette to some variable as `current_palette = sns.color_palette()`.
- Third, note that that object supports `__get_item__`, so you could get the first and second colors in it as

  ```
  first = current_palette[0]
  second = current_palette[1]
  ```
- Fourth: note the `set_palette()` function, which the docs note will accept a list of RGB tuples.
- Finally, make a new palette as

  ```
  sns.set_palette(
      [second, first] + current_palette[2:]
  )
  ```